# How to commit transaction in Keycloak?

Tags: java, transactions, keycloak, wildfly, jta

I work with Keycloak:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>keycloak-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <version>4.4.0.21-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<name>Keycloak WildFly Integration</name>
<description/>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>keycloak-wildfly-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>adduser</module>
    <module>extensions</module>
    <module>server-subsystem</module>
</modules>
```

And in my custom module I'm trying to work with transactions. I get this code from main class KeycloakApplications as an example

```
KeycloakSession session = sessionFactory.create();
   try {
       session.getTransactionManager().begin();
       //do some wokr with db etc.
       session.getTransactionManager().commit();
       ServicesLogger.LOGGER.addUserSuccess(userRep.getUsername(), realmRep.getRealm());
   }
```

But when I use the same method in my code I get this error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction associated with the
> current thread

Full stactrace:

> 15:23:36,668 ERROR [com.mycompany.sso.events.listener.KafkaConsumerProvider] (keycloak-audit-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5) No transaction associated with the current thread: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction associated with the current thread
> at org.wildfly.transaction.client.ContextTransactionManager.commit(ContextTransactionManager.java:69)
> at org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper.commit(JtaTransactionWrapper.java:92)
> at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakTransactionManager.commit(DefaultKeycloakTransactionManager.java:136)
> at com.mycompany.sso.events.listener.KafkaConsumerProvider.process(KafkaConsumerProvider.java:79)
> at akka.stream.javadsl.Source.$anonfun$map$1(Source.scala:1299)
> at akka.stream.impl.fusing.Map$$anon$1.onPush(Ops.scala:54)
> at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:523)
> at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:480)
> at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:376)
> at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:606)
> at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:485)
> at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:581)
> at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:749)
> at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:764)
> at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539)
> at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537)
> at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:671)
> at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:614)
> at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:583)
> at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
> at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
> at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
> at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
> at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
> at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
> at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

My code:

```
try {
        KeycloakTransactionManager transactionManager = session.getTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.begin();
        //do some work
        transactionManager.commit(); //error in this line
    }
```

I debug class org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakTransactionManager with implementations of begin(), commit() and rollback() methods, but it didn't help me figure out what I was doing wrong.

Some screens:

1. TransactionManager before begin()
   [image]
2. Transaction manager after begin()
   [image]
3. Transaction manager after some work, but before commit
   [image]

Could anyone tell me why this error is happening?

Comment: I would add: 1) more of your code and 2) the full stacktrace of the exception

Comment: @Gimby Thank You for advice! I past my full stactrace. But there is no important code in my example, simply begin() and commit(). The problem is still reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake is that I do few transations in one session. It is problematic in Keycloak (see https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2014-September/000898.html)
When I create new session each time, it worked.

But maybe there is more correct way to solve my problem?